# Github- Cloning a private repo to a public repo

Tags: git, github

I am currently making an android project under the supervision of my professor who has given me access to the private repo he created for the project. I was wondering whether I can make another repo(public) so that the project can be reflected onto my profile and any one can see that?

Also is there any way to **sync** these two repos so that if I ppush to one, other automatically gets updated?

I am new at **github** and it would be a great help to me.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to add the other repo as remote to your client, and push to it, in the terminal you can do something like this:

```
git remote add public https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

and then

```
git push public master
```

if you are using some kind of UI for git you can add the remote that way and push.

Comment: So, do I have to clone the public repo on my local system too? Like I did for the private repository.

Comment: you will run this code in your clone of the private repo. if you run git push origin master you will push your changes to the private repo, if you push to git push origin master, you will push your changes to your public repo

Answer (score 0):

You can fork the repo, and any changes you make can be kept separate from the main branch.  As for sync, it's up to the owner of each repository to determine if they want to merge branches and mainline any changes.  I hope that helps clear some of the confusion.

Of course, this is tailored to your circumstance.  It is possible to syncronize two repositories, however that's a job for automation or manual concentration.

If you insist on the "syncing multiple repositories" aspect, take a look here:
https://blog.afoolishmanifesto.com/posts/syncing-with-multiple-git-repos/

Comment: that could work, but don't know if you could fork a private repo into a public repo.

Comment: I admit, my logic on this is quasi-fuzzy.